# If I get banned from meta.stackoverflow.com, am I also banned from stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, stack-overflow, meta, ban

I have googled and haven't really found an answer. I have had a couple of questions get severely downvoted here (one was a support question too, thx). If I get auto-banned on meta, will it affect my ability to post stackoverflow.com? I've read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta but some other questions seem to imply that its site wide.

Comment: How would you manage to get banned here?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Maybe by repeatedly insulting unicorns, marking up screen shots with subtle-colored perfectly neat outlines made with an ellipse tool or square tool, or taking the name of J-n Sk--t in vain?

Comment: @AdiInbar unicorns? Gah! Those things? They drive me nuts! And non-free hand circles are the best kind! Are you serious? Oh my Jon Skeet!

Comment: @ColeJohnson We'll miss you around here. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If I get auto-banned on meta, will it affect my ability to post stackoverflow.com?

No.

> some other questions seem to imply that its site wide.

Yes. However, Meta and SO are considered different sites.

Comment: so meta downvotes are separate but banned from SO would be SO, superuser, etc...?

Comment: @timpone No. SO is a different site from SU.

Comment: @timpone No, every SE site is separate.

Comment: thx for answer... have to wait