# Does positive activity on one SE site help to get out of a ban on another site?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have read [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997) but I need to clarify something:

I was banned from Stack Overflow when I was a new user. Since then, I have been quite active on several other SE sites, and have received quite positive, useful and green reviews.

Do I have to get more reputation and points on Stack Overflow specifically to get out of my ban, or does giving positive feedback and earning reputation on other SE sites help with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus I have already this answer. All I want to know is, whether I have to provide useful answers on this specific platform where I have been banned OR providing useful feedbacks and answers on other sites be helpful too in lifting the ban?

Comment: Given this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194075/230506 Which insinuates that all sites are separate, I would hazard a guess that you have to fix on the site you are banned.

Comment: @James thanks. That was what I was looking for . But is that an official answer or is it just s random guess?

Comment: Not official per-se. Answer has a few upvotes and is from high rep user, and other users commented who are well versed around the sites, and it's not contested nor downvoted at all. But that's not concrete, just a "probably". Hence why I commented and not answered :) Someone will confirm soon. It makes sense you have to fix on the same site, as it's relative - you do some good things on the *same* site you have a ban on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, all communities are separate and interactions on one site will not at all affect automated post blocks on another. Similarly, actions made on a per-site-meta do not affect your posting blocks on the main site, and vice versa.

In order to lift the block, you will have to continue participating and improving *on the site where you are blocked*.

Comment: What do migrations do to this - can a question be migrated if the user has a question ban?

Comment: @Tim: if a user has a question ban on one site, their question on another site will be blocked from migration to the first site. You can't get around a question ban by posting on another site and hoping your question gets migrated.

Comment: @AlE. Is there meta / faq / help page saying that?

Comment: @Tim: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114975/21960 & http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112598/21960

Comment: @AlE. Ta, nice to know that works! :)