# To what extent might scores, on my posts on one SE site, affect scores on another?

Tags: discussion, support, voting, stack-exchange

As my formal training in biology was limited to about 40 hours, half a century ago, in a classroom of a state school system that had been (and remains) legally banned from discussion of a concept generally considered fundamental to biology (Darwin's Theory of Evolution), supplemented by only about 17 hours of reading at home, I was disappointed to receive only negative votes on the biology site.

Nearly all of my posting on Stack Exchange sites has been on the Physics Stack Exchange and its Meta partner, as I have a curiosity about cosmological issues that's very strong.

Before perhaps undeleting my question to the Biology Stack Exchange, I'd like to know the extent to which negative and/or zero scores on that SE site might, directly or indirectly, affect my standing on the Physics SE.

Comment: The sites are pretty-much self-contained except in the event of a network-wide ban for repeatedly or badly breaking the [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), which I doubt that you're in any danger of doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does positive activity on one SE site help to get out of a ban on another site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255870/does-positive-activity-on-one-se-site-help-to-get-out-of-a-ban-on-another-site)

Comment: No, I hadn't been worried about a ban:  The question I'd posted on the Biology SE had asked for verification about the possibility that suicide by extreme (by terrestrial standards) exposure to radiation might be painless, and the only verbal reply I'd gotten  had, aside from some irrelevant remarks that seemed to bear on recovery from brief but complete heart failure, mentioned that neurological signals travel at velocities very much lower than the speed of light, which was exactly what I'd wanted to verify.  I was aware that nerves are neither wires nor extended synapses.

Comment: I was not concerned with points on a branch of SE that I'll rarely utilize:  I was (and remain) concerned about destruction of biological life on an extremely large scale (again, by terrestrial standards).

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog -I undeleted my question on the Biology SE, with several edits.  Your clarification and references were helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They don't.

In almost no cases is your activity on one site impactful of any other site. Some users have excellent reception on one site but end up with downvotes or even suspensions on others. We do not *generally* take actions on one site into account on others.

In fact, moderators can only see problematic content - including deleted posts - on their own sites (unless they also have sufficient reputation to see deleted content on other sites) - so they can not base any actions on other sites.

There are only a few situations I can think of off-hand:

1. **Association Bonus** - when you earn 200 reputation on one site, you get 100 reputation on all sites you've joined.
2. **Network-wide suspensions** - a very tiny number of users are so problematic that they are suspended on a network-wide basis. This can only be done by staff and is limited to very rare situations.
3. **Rate limits** - some rate limits will restrict the number of questions that can be posted within a period of time. This is generally something only lower-reputation users run into and it is related to IP, not account.

Otherwise, all site restrictions are isolated to that specific site - this includes question and answer bans, and regular suspensions.

Comment: Migrations are another example, where content literally moves sites.

Comment: Yeah, but even in that case, we intentionally strip votes off negative scoring questions - if you've done well, that can go with you but if you've done poorly, the votes are all wiped out.